# TLS over unix pipe

Tags: pipe, ssl, openssl, tls

Can I use TLS/SSL over Unix pipe with Unix command line?

I want the equivalent of

```
$ mkfifo /tmp/spipe
$ echo a|openssl s_server -acceptFifo /tmp/spipe &
[1] 25563
$ openssl s_client -connectFifo /tmp/spipe
a
[1]   Done                    echo a|openssl s_server -acceptFifo /tmp/spipe
```

(Yes, it's not hard to write a short program to do that, but I was hoping it is possible with existing tools)

Let me clarify, I do not want a tcp connection any time in the process. I want to use the TLS/SSL protocol over a UNIX pipe. The client will open a unix pipe, and will connect to the server "listening" on another pipe. I do NOT want to move data from TLS tcp connection to a pipe.

Comment: TLS is bidrectional, so you need two pipes or a "bi-directional pipe"  which can be simulated by `dpipe` from the vde2 package.

Comment: @jofel, correct. I'll have a look at the vde2 package. Thanks

Comment: Why?  Encryption is pointless for local communication.

Comment: @psusi see comments in the answer below. It's mostly useful for debugging.

Comment: There's one aspect you won't be able to debug with unix sockets: host name verification. I'm not sure it even makes sense to use a certificate valid for `localhost` for a unix socket.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`socat`](http://www.dest-unreach.org/socat/).

```
#client
socat PIPE:/tmp/spipe OPENSSL:server:4443,cafile=server.crt,cert=client.pem

#server
socat -u OPENSSL-LISTEN:4443,reuseaddr,pf=ip4,fork,cert=server.pem,cafile=client.crt PIPE:/tmp/spipe
```

`socat` has lots of features, so you could maybe avoid the pipes at all.

**EDIT**: added the `-u` (unidirectional) option to server's socat - without it, the pipe works as an *echo* service.

Comment: Your method opens a TCP connection, and does not use unix pipes to move the data. It will move the plaintext data from the tcp TLS connection to a pipe, but it will not use TLS when moving data through the pipe. It's equivalent to `openssl s_client -connect host` and `openssl s_server`. Please correct your answer.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood your questions. I think what you want is not possible with socat - so I will delete my answer soon. But why do you want a local ssl pipe? For me, this makes no sense at all.

Comment: It's really handy for debugging purposes. For instance, you can test an HTTP proxy with `(echo -e 'CONNECT example.com 443 HTTP/1.1';tlsOnPipe)|nc proxyserver 8080`. It can also make sense if you want to use TLS authentication (say, client cert), and to expose your service through tcp and through unix pipes.